# Class type parameters in Scala.

Tags: scala, generic-variance

I'm having difficulty writing something that should be quite straight-forward, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

I have a class hierarchy for foods:

```
Food :> Vegetable :> Bamboo
```

And for animals:

```
Animal :> Herbivore :> Panda
```

And I'm trying to define an eat method in Animal, so that Pandas can't eat Vegetables in general, only Bamboo. At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
class Food(val name : String)
class Vegetable(name: String) extends Food(name)
class Bamboo extends Vegetable("bamboo")

class Animal[F <: Food](val name : String) {
    def eat[T <: F](f : T) = println(s"$name eats some yummy ${f.name}")
}
class Herbivore[F <: Vegetable](name :String) extends Animal[Vegetable](name)
class Panda extends Herbivore[Bamboo]("panda")
```

my trouble is, that when I create a Vegetable, the Panda can eat it:

```
(new Panda) eat (new Vegetable("potato"))
```

So something's going wrong :(

Any help would be very welcome :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change:

```
class Herbivore[F <: Vegetable](name :String) extends Animal[Vegetable](name)
```

to:

```
class Herbivore[F <: Vegetable](name :String) extends Animal[F](name)
```

Otherwise you're throwing out the type information by not using F.

Comment: Many thanks :) that fixes the panda.eat(potato) problem. Now I have the problem, that a (new Herbivore("cow")).eat(new Bamboo) doesn't compile :( ---- sorry, i shouldn't call it a cow, let's call it new Herbivore("generic herbivore")

Comment: @ehrt1974 `new Herbivore[Vegetable]("generic herbivore").eat(new Bamboo)`

Comment: I also don't think it makes sense for `Animal` and `Herbivore` to be non abstract classes.